# Method chaining chomp/chompbang

Tags: ruby

Why does `chomp` allow chaining but `chomp!` doesn't? For example:

```
"HELLO ".chomp.downcase
#> hello
"HELLO ".chomp!.downcase
#> nil
```

Another interesting example:

```
"100 ".chomp.to_i
#> 100
"100 ".chomp!.to_i
#> 0
```

Any ideas why this behavior occurs on the string, and why `nil.to_i` returns `0`?

Comment: 1) Your example is wrong. 2) You should separate your two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chomp):

> **chomp(separator=$/) → new_str**
>
> Returns a new `String` with the given record separator removed from the end of *str* (if present). If `$/` has not been changed from the default Ruby record separator, then `chomp` also removes carriage return characters (that is it will remove `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n`).

and for [`chomp!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chomp-21):

> **chomp!(separator=$/) → str or nil**
>
> Modifies *str* in place as described for `String#chomp`, returning *str*, or `nil` if no modifications were made.

So neither `chomp` nor `chomp!` do what you think they do. Observe:

```
>> s = '100 '
=> "100 "
>> s.chomp
=> "100 "
>> s
=> "100 "
>> s.chomp!
=> nil
>> s
=> "100 "
```

So neither one cares about trailing spaces unless you tell them to, they just strip off trailing EOLs by default.

`'100 '.chomp!` returns `nil` because that's what the documentation says it does. No substitution was made so it returns `nil`.

Why does `nil.to_i` give you zero? Well, from the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i):

> **to_i → 0**
>
> Always returns zero.

That doesn't leave much room for ambiguity or interpretation.

I think you're actually after the `strip` family of methods rather than `chomp`:

- [`String#lstrip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-lstrip)
- [`String#lstrip!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-lstrip-21)
- [`String#rstrip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-rstrip)
- [`String#rstrip!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-rstrip-21)
- [`String#strip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-strip)
- [`String#strip!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-strip-21)

Those remove whitespace from the string.

Answer (score 2):

Your question will vanish if you remember to provide an argument to chomp. Without one, chomp will only remove newlines and carriage returns, which are absent from your string. The bang augmented chomp returns nil because it hasn't done any modification (as per the documentation).

In brief, you really wanted to write:

```
"HELLO ".chomp(" ").downcase
 => hello
```

And:

```
"HELLO ".chomp!(" ").downcase
 => hello
```